# Keep selected filters when navigating between pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The code below is responsible for building the sidebar on the site. In this case, the sidebar is 2 filter options, made in the form of a drop-down list.

This side bar is located on all pages of the site. However, the problem is that when switching between pages, the selected filter options are not saved. That is, if on the first page, the user checks something in the filters, then when going to the second page, the values ​​in the filters will not be saved. And I would like the selected parameters for filtering to be saved when moving from page to page.

```
    export default function App() {
  return (
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme} style="width: 100vw; height: 100vh">
          <Header/>
          <BrowserRouter>
              <Routes>
                  <Route exact path='/test' element={<Test filterKey='device'/>}/>
                  <Route exact path='/devices' element={<DeviceList/>}/>
                  <Route exact path='/devices/:deviceId' element={<DeviceId/>}/>
                  <Route exact path='/devices/:deviceId/:userId' element={<UserId/>}/>
                  <Route exact path='/devices/:deviceId/:userId/:sessionId' element={<SessionId/>}/>
                  <Route exact path='/devices/:deviceId/:userId/:sessionId/:pocketId' element={<PocketId/>}/>
                  <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/devices" replace />}/>
              </Routes>
              <Footer/>
          </BrowserRouter>
      </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

Comment: Try to save filter data to local storage and check local storage object before loading default values. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: @MadduSwaroop Thank you. I will familiarize myself with this material, if it is not very difficult. Since I don't learn React and Javascript for very long.

Comment: @Павел look into react-redux: https://react-redux.js.org/. This is a technology that has been specifically designed for state management across components in react applications and fits your use case.

Comment: Why not putting your Sidebar in App component since you say, it exist in each page with same filters?

Comment: @Evren Yes, I'm trying to do it now, but so far without success. In the condition I have provided the App code. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are saying `Sidebar` component should be in each page with same functionality, I would place it in `App` component then it will be always in pages without changing it's filters

```
export default function App() {
  return (
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme} style="width: 100vw, height: 100vh">
      <BrowserRouter>

          <Header/>

          <div style={{width: '100%', display: 'flex'}}>

           <Routes>
             <Route exact path='/test' element={<Test filterKey='device'/>}/>
             <Route exact path='/devices' element={<DeviceList/>}/>
             <Route exact path='/devices/:deviceId' element={<DeviceId/>}/>
             <Route exact path='/devices/:deviceId/:userId' element={<UserId/>}/>
             <Route exact path='/devices/:deviceId/:userId/:sessionId' element={<SessionId/>}/>
            <Route exact path='/devices/:deviceId/:userId/:sessionId/:pocketId' element={<PocketId/>}/>
            <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/devices" replace />}/>
           </Routes>

           <Sidebar />

          </div>

          <Footer/>

         </BrowserRouter> 
      </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

Comment: Yes thank you! But there is probably something wrong in your code. Fully underlined in red.

Comment: I see, thanks. But now there is an error: useHref() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component. Can this be fixed somehow?

Comment: Check my edits @Павел

Comment: Yes! It works. The idea is clear to me. Thank you.
Only now my styles are violated, but this is another problem) Perhaps only you can tell me how to move it to the left side of the screen (since in your example the sidebar is now on the right)

Comment: You are welcome :) Just put Sidebar component before <Routes>. In my example I put it after </Routes> @Павел

Answer (score 0):

to share the `State` between `React Components` you can initiate your state in the `main App` and then pass it to all components via `props`. 
 
*for example*, your **"Component A"** :

```
// pass the state & setState in the component as props :
export const ComponentA = ({
  isFilterMethodExpanded,
  setIsFilterMethodExpanded,
  isFilterDateTimeExpanded,
  setIsFilterDateTimeExpanded
}) => {
  // whatever you want to do with the state
  return <div>...</div>;
};
```

and your **"Component B"** :

```
// pass the state & setState in the component as props :
export const ComponentB = ({
  isFilterMethodExpanded,
  setIsFilterMethodExpanded,
  isFilterDateTimeExpanded,
  setIsFilterDateTimeExpanded
}) => {
  // whatever you want to do with the state
  return <div>...</div>;
};
```

then your **main App** will look like :

```
// Initiate the state in the main App :
export default function App() {
  const [isFilterMethodExpanded, setIsFilterMethodExpanded] = useState(false);
  const [isFilterDateTimeExpanded, setIsFilterDateTimeExpanded] = useState(
    false
  );
  // pass the state & setState in the component props in the return part :
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ComponentA
        isFilterMethodExpanded={isFilterMethodExpanded}
        setIsFilterMethodExpanded={setIsFilterMethodExpanded}
        isFilterDateTimeExpanded={isFilterDateTimeExpanded}
        setIsFilterDateTimeExpanded={setIsFilterDateTimeExpanded}
      />
      <ComponentB
        isFilterMethodExpanded={isFilterMethodExpanded}
        setIsFilterMethodExpanded={setIsFilterMethodExpanded}
        isFilterDateTimeExpanded={isFilterDateTimeExpanded}
        setIsFilterDateTimeExpanded={setIsFilterDateTimeExpanded}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

This will keep the `State` when navigating between `React Components`, but **not on the browser refresh**, If you want to `Persist` the `State` on page reload then you can check [this article](https://blog.bitsrc.io/5-methods-to-persisting-state-between-page-reloads-in-react-8fc9abd3fa2f)